# Transition vs transform

Tags: difference

What’s the difference between *transition* and *transform*?

They both can be used as verb, like *transform (something) into* or *transition (something) to/into (something)*, but what is the main difference between them?

Comment: A caterpillar *transforms* into a butterfly, but I wouldn't say it *transitions* into one. When you toggle Light/Dark Mode for your browser, the window *transitions* from one to the other, but I'd never say it *transforms*. Not sure how universal this is, but to me it seems like "transform" means "one thing *becomes* something else," while "transition" means "one thing *is superseded by/replaced with/gives way to* something else." With "transition," the original entity does not necessarily change.

Comment: as @QuackE.Duck states, "trasnsform" means to take on a new form, as a caterpillar (or Transformer toy!). "Transition" is any change, e.g., transitioning from standard time to daylight time, or from a petrol to an electric powered vehicle.

Comment: This really needs context.  What is the context in which you want to use the words.  There are some situations which only "transform" is natural.  And there are some in which only "transition" is natural.  But there are too many contexts for an answer to consider all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those cases where dictionary definitions can be misleading because they don't convey subtle nuances of meaning.

I'd use "transform" for dramatic changes, that is, truly change "form", and "transition" for more subtle changes, like change within a type.

Like, "Bob transitioned from being a waiter to being a chef." He's still working in food service but he has a different job. But, "Bob transformed from working in food service to working as a lawyer." A totally different role.

But "big" vs "small" change can be very subjective. Is day to night a whole different thing, or just a different amount of light? Etc.